# How can I center an image?

Tags: css

I'm building a website and At the top of the website I have a  that has a background-image. The background-image takes up the whole div but I don't want it to. I want the image to keep it's original dimensions and center itself horizontally. How would I do this?

Comment: Try `text-align: center` on the container. Add your html so we can have a clue as to what you're doing.

Comment: Since it is a background image, use the css background property `background:url(path) no-repeat center center;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `background:url(path_to_image) no-repeat center center;` in the css for the background div.

```css
.bg{
background:url(http://via.placeholder.com/350x150) no-repeat center center;
height:250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
</div>
```